# Get items from Ruby Array that occur 2 or more times

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a Ruby array.

```
[1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,7]
```

I want to find the values that occur 2 or more times.

```
[4,6,7]
```

It will help my process to first determine which items occur only once then remove those. So I'd like to solve this by first finding the items that occur once.

Comment: You have marked as "accepted" an answer that works, but that has terrible performance possibilities. I humbly request that you review the answers again and accept an answer that exhibits better algorithmic design.

Comment: I was just asking another commenter why the one I accepted wasn't better. Performance I can understand. Algorithmic design, not so much.

Comment: In my opinion, algorithmic design is more important than performance. Micro-optimizations to eek out the very best performance are rarely appropriate, while writing code that does not suddenly take over the machine when the dataset size doubles is very, very important.

Comment: And further down the rabbit hole. I'm a fairly practical programmer, but it has honestly been since my early education since I really thought about this. Only when I've had a performance issue have I put thought into the design of my algorithms. Well I plan to change all that. [This article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-principles-of-algorithm-design--net-26561) is my read for today, but many more to come. Thanks again for the comments.

Comment: I want to tell one more interesting tidbit. The reason behind this question actually deals with some scoping that I'm doing in Rails. Not to disparage ptierno's response, but when that method was translated into a scope it took over 15 seconds to get the response. I went with Paul's answer for my final code and I get my response in less than 100ms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are probably better ways, but this is one:

```
> [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,7].group_by{|i| i}.reject{|k,v| v.size == 1}.keys
=> [4, 6, 7]
```

Breaking it down:

```
> a = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,7]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7]
> a1 = a.group_by{|i| i}
=> {1=>[1], 2=>[2], 3=>[3], 4=>[4, 4], 5=>[5], 6=>[6, 6], 7=>[7, 7]}
> a2 = a1.reject{|k,v| v.size == 1}
=> {4=>[4, 4], 6=>[6, 6], 7=>[7, 7]}
> a2.keys
=> [4, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Voted up. This is the best answer so far.

Comment: @sawa What's better about this answer? The one I accepted seems simpler. Not being rude I really want to know.

Comment: Read my comment to that answer.

Comment: @RyanBurnette basically the original answer you accepted is incredibly inefficient. For large arrays it would start to get really slow

Comment: I love when a question causes me to learn something I didn't even expect. It's something I knew mattered but I had gotten into the habit of not thinking about. After reconsidering the breakdown I really do see the efficiency, and it makes a huge difference in my use case. Thanks again.

Comment: Ryan - if you have huge arrays use Paul.s' solution. It's still O(n) but will have a smaller memory footprint as is only keeps the count. Should be a teensy bit faster.

Comment: Actually I suppose worst case our solutions are O(2n). Assuming an array with no repeating values. But still much faster than O(n^2)

Answer (score 3):

Everyone loves a really difficult to follow one liner :)

```
[1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,7].each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |o, h| h[o] += 1 }.select { |_, v| v > 1 }.keys
```

Add some white space and some comments

```
[1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,7].each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |o, h| 
  h[o] += 1 
}.select { |_, v| 
  v > 1 
}.keys
```

- Enumerate and pass in our memo hash to each iteration the Hash defaults to having `0` for any key
- Increment counter for the object
- Select only key value pairs where the value is greater than 1
- Grab just the keys

---

This looks quite similar to Phillip's neat answer - in theory this should use slightly less memory as it will not have to build the intermediate arrays to perform counting

Comment: Nice. I was thinking about the memory issues in my solution just a little while ago. Glad someone posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,7]
au = a.uniq
a.reject { |i| au.delete(i) }
  #=> [4, 6, 7]
```

If efficiency is important, you could use a set:

```
require 'set'

s = Set.new
a.reject { |e| s.add?(e) }
  #=> [4, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) to return the elements where [Array#count](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-count) is greater than 1:

```
2.1.2 :005 > arr = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,7]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7]
2.1.2 :006 > arr.select { |e| arr.count(e) > 1 }.uniq
 => [4, 6, 7]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is at least O(n^2).